# Combine Get-ADGroupMember and Get-AD user

Tags: powershell

I have two scripts: one to pull group membership, and the other to pull name, email address and title from the users list that is received from the first script.

I need to combine both these scripts and get output with group name, user details, user info in same Excel file.

Please help.

To get group membership:

```sh
import-module activedirectory
$groups = "groupname"
$result = foreach($group in $groups){Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Select @{Label="Group Name";Expression={$group}}, SamAccountName}
$result | Export-Csv .\Output_GroupInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

To get user properties:

```sh
import-module activedirectory
gc .\Input_User.txt | Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title | select DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title | Export-Csv .\Output_UserInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line without first storing the outputs separately, by piping AD cmdlets together. Here I store group data in adgrp variable to use down the pipeline:

```
$groups | Get-ADGroup -OutVariable adgrp | Get-ADGroupMember | 
Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName,EmailAddress,Title | 
select DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title, @{n='GroupName';e={$adgrp.Name}}, @{n='GroupSamAccountName';e={$adgrp.SamAccountName}}
```